# Select one row from non unique rows based on row value

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, case, conditional-statements

I have a quiz table

```
id  | user_id | quiz_id
--------------------------
1   | 34567   | 12334
2   | 34567   | 12334
3   | 34567   | 23455
```

id 1 and 2 depicts a quiz that can be assigned to the same user twice

and a quiz transaction table

```
id  | date | status
------------------------
1   | 2014 | assigned
2   | 2014 | assigned
3   | 2014 | assigned
------------------------
1   | 2014 | completed
```

`id` is foreign key to quiz table id, the last row depicts whenever a user finished the quiz, the row in the transaction table is updated with status 'completed'

Expected Result: I want a table with a structure like

```
id  | user_id| course_id | date | status
------------------------------------------
1   | 34567  | 12334     | 2014 | completed
2   | 32567  | 12334     | 2014 | assigned
3   | 2014   | 23455     | 2014 | assigned
```

My query is

```
SELECT  q.id, q.user_id, q.course_id, qt.date, qt.status FROM quiz q 
LEFT JOIN 
quiz_transaction qt  ON 
q.id = qt.id
```

but it gives me extra row (as the query will)

```
1   | 34567  | 12334     | 2014 | assigned
```

I cannot use

```
ON qt.type = 'completed'
```

Because if its completed it should return a completed row and if not it should return an assigned row but not both.

So in the result I cannot have

```
1   | 34567  | 12334     | 2014 | completed
1   | 34567  | 12334     | 2014 | assigned
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about simply using the `MAX()` function with `GROUP BY` ([**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/39ac3/1/0)):

```
SELECT  q.id, q.user_id, q.course_id, qt.date, MAX(qt.status) AS Status
FROM quiz q 
LEFT JOIN quiz_transaction qt ON q.id = qt.id 
GROUP BY q.id, q.user_id, q.course_id, qt.date
```

**EDIT:** If you need to order a string a certain way, you could use a CASE statement to convert the string to a number.  Get the MAX value and then convert it back ([**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e13b9/4/0)):

```
SELECT m.id, m.user_id, m.quiz_id, MAX(m.date), 
  CASE WHEN MAX(m.status) =  1 THEN 'assigned'
       WHEN MAX(m.status) = 2 THEN 'doing'
       WHEN MAX(m.status) = 3 THEN 'completed' END AS Status
FROM 
(
  SELECT q.id, q.user_id, q.quiz_id, qt.date, 
  CASE WHEN qt.status = 'assigned' THEN 1 
       WHEN qt.status = 'doing' THEN 2
       WHEN qt.status = 'completed' THEN 3 END AS Status
  FROM quiz q 
  LEFT JOIN quiz_transaction qt ON q.id = qt.id 
) AS m
GROUP BY m.id, m.user_id, m.quiz_id;
```

Comment: thx it solved my particular problem. I was on my way to do max on dates but now can do on Status. On another point, what if Max() was not an option i.e. status can be assigned, doing, completed and I need to select for example completed.

Comment: Actually it does.  Take a look at the SQL Fiddle I added to my answer.  Notice that in the `quiz_transaction` table there is 2 records for `id 1`.  In the results of the query there is only one row for `ID 1`.  The problem you may be having is you have multiple records in the `quiz` table with the same exact `user_id` and `quiz_id` combination.  But the `id` differs.  Based on the GROUP BY you will get multiple records.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your release SQLnServer supports Standard SQL's "Windowed Aggregate Functions". ROW_NUMBER will give you a single row:

```
SELECT
   q.id
  ,q.user_id
  ,q.quiz_id
  ,qt.date
  ,qt.status
FROM quiz q 
JOIN 
 (
   SELECT
     id
     ,date
     ,status
     ,ROW_NUMBER()
      OVER (PARTITION BY id
            ORDER BY Status DESC) as rn
   FROM quiz_transaction
 ) as qt
ON q.id = qt.id
WHERE rn = 1
```

If you got more complex ordering rules you need to use a CASE:

```
     ,ROW_NUMBER()
      OVER (PARTITION BY id
            ORDER BY CASE Status WHEN 'completed' THEN 1 
                                 WHEN 'doing'     THEN 2
                                 WHEN 'assigned'  THEN 3
                     END) as rn
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT  q.id, q.user_id, q.course_id, q1.date, qt.status FROM quiz q 
         LEFT JOIN 
    (Select id , convert(varchar,max(convert(varbinary,status )))  'Status'
     from     quiz_transaction
    group by id
    ) qt  ON 
         q.id = qt.id 
    left join quiz_transaction q1 on q1.id = qt.id and q1.status=qt.status
```